# Why do clicking on textarea on Facebook login screen in Facebook Connect using fbrocket not popping up keyboard?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using fbrocket for Facebook connect with my android app. It's working fine. For the first time when I'd logged in, the login webpage presented me with a keyboard on press of textareas for username and password.

But now, on the same page, it's showing me a strip of characters that I'm typing that too in different language and they are not rendered.

I'm really confused by this login screen behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there's a bug in sdk which prevents the keyboard from popping if you put webview under a button or menu of some sort. Ie, that it's activated via an onClickListener, onLongClickListener, or onOptionsItemSelected. This issue seems to be getting solved by using

```
          webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

but for using this you at least need the webview instance. But since I'm using fbRocket api which handles the interactions with webview for login and after login uses the callback mentioned to redirect to my application, I don't have the webview instance.

Does anybody have a solution on this issue?

Or am I missing something?